# Limit of an integral sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(I_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence,
$$I_n=\frac{1}{n} \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^1 \ln(1+\cos(x)) \, dx, \forall n\ge1$$
Show that $(I_n)_{n\ge1}$ converges and find its limit.
It is clear that  $I_n>0$ but how do I prove that it is decreasing? As for the limit, I suppose it is $0$ and the squeeze theorem could be used to show that.

Comment: Maybe you could use $\ln(1+cos(x)) \leq \cos(x)$

Comment: The integral converges to $\int_{0}^{1}\log(1+\cos x) \, dx$ so the desired limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$a_n = \frac1n$$
$$b_n = \int_{\frac1n}^1 \log(1 + \cos x) dx$$

Now,

$$a_n \to 0$$
$$b_n \to \int_0^1 \log(1 + \cos x) dx \in \mathbb{R}$$

Therefore $a_n b_n \to 0$.